# Invalid JSON file project.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new in entity framework core and I want to use entity framework core in asp.net core. But when I do add-migration firstMigration it always show below error :

Invalid JSON file in D:\OwnLearnings\EFCore\AspNetCore_EFCore_001\src\AspNetCore_EFCore_001\project.json

Project.json :

```
 {
   "dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
     "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
     "type": "build"
   },
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",

   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
     "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
     "type": "build"
    },


    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
     "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
    },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

 "frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
},

 "buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},

 "runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
    },

 "publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
    },

 "scripts": {
"prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
   }
```

I unable to find what is the error. I am facing this type of problem first time in entity framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: save yourself some grief with the `.json` file get VS2017 (CE if you must) and get with the latest bits that are current, get away from those old preview installs... The msbuild `csproj`is honestly so much better,

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a reference to the Entity framework package in the dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"
```

Also you need the imports for EF Core for executing migrations and updates (command line). This needs to be in the tools seciton (the tools reference also needs to be in the dependencies like you put it, do not remove it)

```
"dependencies": {
...   
},
"tools": {
    ..,
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "Imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
}...
```